# bind9 didn't resolve

Tags: ubuntu, bind

My server OS is Ubuntu 10.04/x86 and now I set the bind's configuration file same as another host (which is Debian 5), and ran `/etc/init.d/bind9 start`.  This shows me `OK`.  I then run `rndc reload`, which returns successful.

I setup the NS server in my domain name's register.  But now, I use the command in client console. `C:\>nslookup domain dns-ip` and is shows me server fault.

So, I want to know what is wrong. I didn't set firewall or other filter system.  I tried to visit http://who.is/ to find the all DNS information, but no record shows, only the 2 NS server which I set was shown.

I have set the bind9 using the same steps in Debian 5 and it's worked well.  Does Ubuntu need additional configuration?

Comment: Bind logs error messages to syslog when you start or restart it, you'll need to check the log files to see what's wrong, probably /var/log/daemon.log

Answer (score 0):

look into /var/log/messages or /var/log/daemon.log

if is the server fault then you have some typo(mistake) into the config files - /var/named/* or /var/named/chroot/var/named (look into /etc/named.conf to what is configured)

chek from the server itself as in

```
host some_name_in_my_list
```

Comment: Or dig @localhost somedomain.com